# How to insert column of other table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I want to insert a column of other table and one parameter of this table have a hard coded value. I want to iterate this value with the each return value of other table column. How can i do this with insert query?

let 3,4,6 is the return column value of other table.

```
insert into table(value1,value2)
values (2,select id from table2)
```

Return column

```
2       3
2       4
2       6
```

Comment: Your question alludes to two tables, and you have only shown one.  The question is hard to follow without appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have changed it. I hope now it'll be clear for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `values` clause:

```
insert into table(value1,value2)
select 2, id 
from table2
```